# Filemaker ExecuteSql adding to aggregate functions

Tags: filemaker

My statement is failing when I try to add something to the value of an aggregate function.

For example, this work fine:

select Min(Lat)
from Points

This fails:

select Min(Lat) + 1
from Points

Is this a bug?  Is there some other syntax I can use to accomplish this?  I'm aware I can just add 1 to the result of the ExecuteSql, but I'm doing something more complex and this is just simplified version of the bug I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
  Min(Lat + 1)
FROM
  Points
```